# How to add a "play button" like overlay image when sharing to Facebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, image-processing, overlay

First of all, this is different from questions like : [How to place an image over another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785458/how-to-place-an-image-over-another)

What I want to know is how to overlay a play button image on top of another existing image, and share it to Facebook. Only way I see is to create a new image with the overlay included. I want to know:

1. If there is any other way to do this than creating a new image. Ideally I don't want to have to store the image to my server.
2. If this is the only way, what is the easiest way to do this? Any library to create this type of image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook takes images from the page, so if you want the image *with* the overlayed play button to display in a Facebook preview, you'll have to generate that image.

In regards to merging 2 images, I'm sure there's heaps of information out there on combining images using imagemagick / rmagick

- http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/image-overlays-with-rmagick-and-rails/
- [Rails 3/ paperclip/ imagemagick - merging two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137342/rails-3-paperclip-imagemagick-merging-two-images)

Answer (score 0):

You can add play button on an image like facebook play button by using adobe photoshop. Watch this video you will understand how to add it on the image.
http://mefmor.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-add-facebook-play-button-in-your.html